# Blank image in profile pictures

Tags: support, bug

I am seeing this for some profile pictures:
[image: A broken image in the user card.]

Comment: I've been seeing it occasionally too. I think it might be a problem with Google users, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10686620/cccc Broken link: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-CrZVzne_CYw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AGDgw-ixWFKM3NBkbQdzeeuegmj_R0qsOw/mo/photo.jpg?sz=32

Comment: I see that for facebook users as well. Are you blocking social stuff?

Comment: I've seen another user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10511664/manish-thakur

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the issue is broken images that was previously hosted by Google, there is not much we can do about it except for mods to reset the user's profile image to use Identicon.

Perhaps the option of using Google profile images should be removed?

Comment: Bonus: anyone blocking google and/or FB directly (IP block, explicit domain block) or indirectly (tracking cookies from a certain book of faces with a tracking graph API) sees broken images for everyone using these services. I'd vote for only using imgur to host profile pictures

Comment: Yeah.. Resetting to Identicon is a good option.

Comment: @Zoe please.. not only imgur. They don't handle transparent images well. gravatar.com can handle transparent images though and some users use that.

Comment: @Scratte Imgur is the main provider for images in general on SE though