# Google user avatars are broken for new users

Tags: feature-request, bug, new-users, profile-picture

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14652223/z3d) signed up less than two hours ago but the profile image is broken.

[image]

I think something should be fixed in signup flow. I would suggest that the image be retrieved from Google and re-hosted on Stack Overflow's Imgur.

I've seen this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400758/blank-image-in-profile-pictures#answer-400759) and how is it going?

Image link broken after 1 hour (or even immediately) from signing up is not a feature. It's a bug, I think.

Comment: [It's a valid image, if you strip off some of the query strings from the end](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj3dwYeVGMA_BeHnhLLzWSLl_o8geLRrCiO-bta2g). I'm not sure how these invalid strings got in there, but this does look like a bug to me.

Comment: @CodyGray I think images from googleusercontent.com are expired after a while, aren't they?

Comment: This is already known: [Invalid size parameters break avatars served by Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355948/289905). This issue isn’t specific to Stack Overflow, so it’s been reported on Meta Stack Exchange.